# Chrome errorcode without statusText problem

Tags: angular, api, .net-core

Maybe someone can explain me why i'm getting response with status code 401 and with empty statustext? I think statustext must be "unauthorized". I'm using action:

```
   [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == loginDto.Username);

            if (user == null)
                return Unauthorized("Invalid username");

            using var hmac = new HMACSHA512(user.PasswordSalt);

            var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(loginDto.Password));

            for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computedHash[i] != user.PasswordHash[i]) return Unauthorized("Invalid password");
            }

            return new UserDto
            {
                Username = user.UserName,
                Token = _tokenService.CreateToken(user)
            };

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason phrases anymore in HTTP/2 anymore.